# How to secure the tomcat start page only?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have a `tomcat` running a web application. Now I'd like to prevent access to `my-dns`, so that users don't see the default tomcat start page (as also shown by `localhost:8080`.

But any applications, eg `my-dns/my-app` should be accessible public.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: have you tried nginx or similar reverse proxies (described below)?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.

1. Use some kind of reverse proxy. This could be [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/). Your servlet-container will be configured on localhost and reverse proxy will proxy all your requests to the desired location.
2. You can rename (or delete it if you don't need tomcat management from the application) the ROOT application to another folder name and put the application you need at http://localhost:8080 in the ROOT folder.

Comment: Personally, I recommend you to think about reverse-proxy (especially if you have several applications in your servlet-container). nginx is extremely simple to use. And you could find various configurations for it in the Internet.